# Ограничение ввода input() (int, float)

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

Доброго времени суток!

Как сделать так чтобы я смог проверить введенные данные во время `input ()` (без помощи `If` и `for`)

Данные только числовые (`int` и `float`)

Например, для `j` мне нужно числа в диапазоне от 2 до 100000 ...

В худшем случае должна выскакивать ошибка (не print ("Ошибка"), а ошибка python)

```py
import numpy as np
rez = list()
j = int(input(""))
for i in range (0, j):
    a, b, c = input("").split(" ")
    a = eval(a)
    b = eval(b)
    c = eval(c)
    v = abs(40 - a) + abs(30 - b) + abs(75 - c)
    rez.append(v)
rez = np.array(rez)    
print(rez.sum())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = -1
try:
    x = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    if 2 > x < 10000:
        raise ValueError()
except ValueError:
    print("Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again...")

print(x)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Но ведь условие то неправильное ))

Comment: странно, автор вопроса вроде хотел решение _без помощи If и for_, но этот ответ его устроил))

Answer (score 0):

нужное исключение можно еще вызвать примерно так:

```
a = 100000
assert 2 < a < 10000, "Введено недопустимое значение"
'''
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-863-dc06aae1cd56> in <module>
      1 a = 100000
----> 2 assert 2 < a < 10000, "Введено недопустимое значение"

AssertionError: Введено недопустимое значение
```